# Mysql сортировка по алфавиту когда есть только индекс

Tags: php, mysql

подскажите, как сделать сортировку по алфавиту:
Например есть таблица где указаны товары:
id, title, cat_id...
Есть таблица каталога (собственно куда ссылается cat_id): id, title...
Нужно выбрать все товары, но отсортировать их по ORDER BY title  ASC из таблицы каталога

Comment: и в чем именно вопрос у вас возник?

Comment: В чём проблема-то, ORDER BY title ASC не работает или что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`goods [id, title, cat_id, ...]` - таблица товаров. 
`catalog [id, title, ...]` - таблица каталога.

```
SELECT g.*, c.* 
FROM goods AS g 
LEFT JOIN catalog 
AS c 
ON g.cat_id = c.id 
ORDER BY c.title ASC;
```